Why does the body jump out at great speed when it collides with the Segment shape in Pymunk?
import pyglet
import pymunk.pyglet_util

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1280, 720
WINDOW = pyglet.window.Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
SPACE = pymunk.Space()
SPACE.gravity = 0, -999
DRAW_OPTIONS = pymunk.pyglet_util.DrawOptions()

circle_body = pymunk.Body(1000, 999)
circle_body.position = WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2 + 200
circle_shape = pymunk.Circle(circle_body, 30)
SPACE.add(circle_body, circle_shape)

# a body for all platforms shapes
platforms_body = pymunk.Body(body_type=pymunk.Body.STATIC)

platform1 = pymunk.Segment(platforms_body, (WIDTH / 2 - 300, HEIGHT / 2 - 100), (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2 - 200), 2)

SPACE.add(platform1, platforms_body)

@WINDOW.event
def on_draw():
    WINDOW.clear()
    SPACE.debug_draw(DRAW_OPTIONS)


def update(dt):
    SPACE.step(dt)

pyglet.clock.schedule(update)
pyglet.app.run()

By running this code, as soon as the ball collides with an object, it is abruptly thrown out in most cases.
This is by no means the first such case when working with Pymunk, but I could not create a test situation in which this would happen all the time, and so... it appeared.
I would really like to know if there is at least some way to correct this misunderstanding, to make it at least less noticeable, or can we just accept and hope for a miracle???
I tried to reduce damping, but still did not solve the problem in all cases.

I tried running the code, but I dont understand the issue. Can you include a picture or video of what you see?

https://youtu.be/wKd9t1DxX9A - From launch to launch, the result is different

With your comment I managed to reproduce the issue exactly once, but after that no more for some reason.
Anyway, I can see 2 potential problems, one minor, and one that likely affect the simulation:
First and most important: The timestep passed into step function is not fixed, instead you use dt from the update function. Pymunk works best when the time step is fixed between the frames. The biggest issue this creates is unstable simulation, for example if you build a tower of boxes. But I also think the issue here can happen. Instead its much better to have a fixed size. There is a couple of links in the Pymunk documentation here: https://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/overview.html#game-loop-moving-time-forward but its actually common for most/all physics engines. See for example this Reddit thread which discusses the problem https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/uktah1/comment/i7w84g1/
If you set a fixed value, lets say 1/30.0, and then adjust the scheduling to call the physics with the same schedule, I think it will be much more stable. For example like this:
STEP_DT = 1 / 30.0

def update(dt):
    SPACE.step(STEP_DT)

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, STEP_DT)

(There are more advanced options, like those mentioned in the Reddit thread, but that if they are needed depends on your requirements of course)
Secondly, a minor issue that I thought to mention, even if I dont think it should have big impact in this case: You set the moment to 1000 on the circle. This is a very low value. If you instead let pymunk calculate moment by setting the mass on the shape instead, the moment will be set to 450000:
circle_body = pymunk.Body()
circle_body.position = WIDTH / 2 + 20, HEIGHT / 2 + 200
circle_shape = pymunk.Circle(circle_body, 30)
circle_shape.color = 255, 255, 255, 255
circle_shape.mass = 1000


While driving home I got the idea that maybe it would be good to adjust the API of the Pymunk.Space somehow to make it easier to avoid the time step issue. The design now makes it very easy to make mistake.
